# Get a caller class instance from another object

Tags: php

Please take a look at this code:

```
class Foo {

   public $barInstance;

   public function test() {
      $this->barInstance = new Bar();
      $this->barInstance->fooInstance = $this;
      $this->barInstance->doSomethingWithFoo();
   }

}

class Bar {
   public $fooInstance;

   public function doSomethingWithFoo() {
       $this->fooInstance->something();
   }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->test();
```

Question: is it possible to let the "`$barInstance"` know from which class it was created (or called) without having the following string: `"$this->barInstance->fooInstance = $this;"`

Comment: What is your motivation for avoiding that line? You haven't provided one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, you might be able to do it with [`debug_backtrace()`](http://us.php.net/debug_backtrace), which as objects in the stack trace, but you better not do it, it's not good coding. 
I think the best way for you would be to pass the parent object in Bar's ctor:

```
class Foo {

    public $barInstance;

    public function test() {
       $this->barInstance = new Bar($this);
       $this->barInstance->doSomethingWithFoo();
    }
}

class Bar {
    protected $fooInstance;

    public function __construct(Foo $parent) {
         $this->fooInstance = $parent;
    }

    public function doSomethingWithFoo() {
        $this->fooInstance->something();
    }
}
```

This limits the argument to being proper type (`Foo`), remove the type if it's not what you want. Passing it in the ctor would ensure `Bar` is never in the state when `doSomethingWithFoo()` would fail.

Comment: `debug_backtrace` will spit back information about the execution, not actual object instances as he would like.

Comment: @mhitza part of debug_backtrace() output (namely 'object' parameter) is the $this that was used in caller method - i.e. in you case `Foo` instance. Put a call to debug_backtrace() in `Bar` ctor and see what it produces. Don't try this at home (e.g. in real code) though - it's bad style to use debug functions for non-debug purposes and may lead to tons of reliability problems (e.g., how you ensure only Foo instantiates Bar?)

Comment: indeed, among the values of `debug_backtrace` are actual instance of the objects.